# Jackson - Unwrap nested attributes

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have an xml like this

```
<TopLevel attr1="foo">
    <Midlevel attr2="bar">
        <BottomLevel>
            <data1>blahblah</data1>
            <data2>blahblah</data2>
        </BottomLevel>
        ...more bottom level elements...
    </Midlevel>
...moreMidLevelElements...
</TopLevel>
```

Now I know that the @JsonUnwrapped annotation can help with one level (which it shows in all the examples). But when I try to deserialize a BottomLevel object which captures the attributes of the outer layers, I just get nulls for everything.

Can anyone help me flatten this xml? I've tried to generalize the question. Ideally, the end result would be List

My pojo has the fields
data1
data2
attr1
attr2

Comment: What do you mean by end result will be a list?

Comment: I'd like to deserialize the above xml into a List<BottomLevel>, where that objects contains data1, data2, and both attributes from the wrapping elements. Basically I want to "flatten" this xml into a single object.

Comment: I want to do this because I'll be persisting this pojo into a database as well as converting it into a csv, and having one entity to work off of would be the most convenient.

Comment: I am a little lost with how exactly should your pojo look like.

Comment: public class whatever{ private String data1, data2, attr1, attr2 }

Answer (score 1):

Don't think this is the perfect answer to this question but it can help to solve the problem you are having. (In a hacky way)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String xml = "<TopLevel attr1=\"foo\">\n" +
            "    <Midlevel attr2=\"bar\">\n" +
            "        <BottomLevel>\n" +
            "            <data1>blahblah</data1>\n" +
            "            <data2>blahblah</data2>\n" +
            "        </BottomLevel>\n" +
            "    </Midlevel>\n" +
            "    <Midlevel attr2=\"bar2\">\n" +
            "        <BottomLevel>\n" +
            "            <data1>blahblah2</data1>\n" +
            "            <data2>blahblah2</data2>\n" +
            "        </BottomLevel>\n" +
            "    </Midlevel>\n" +
            "</TopLevel>";

    ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    System.out.println(xmlMapper.readValue(xml, TopLevel.class)); //Once here, you can now do custom mapping with the TopLevel class object to your custom POJO
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
static class TopLevel {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String attr1;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Midlevel", useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Midlevel")
    private List<MidLevel> midLevel = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TopLevel{" +
                "attr1='" + attr1 + '\'' +
                ", midLevel=" + midLevel +
                '}';
    }
}

static class MidLevel {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String attr2;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "BottomLevel", useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "BottomLevel")
    private List<BottomLevel> bottomLevels = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MidLevel{" +
                "attr2='" + attr2 + '\'' +
                ", bottomLevels=" + bottomLevels +
                '}';
    }
}

static class BottomLevel {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "data1")
    private String data1;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "data2")
    private String data2;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BottomLevel{" +
                "data1='" + data1 + '\'' +
                ", data2='" + data2 + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I see what you're saying. So parse it from xml using 3 classes, AND THEN convert it to a single class.

Comment: Yep, exactly. Once you have TopLevel class object, map it according to your needs.

Comment: Like you mentioned it's a little bit hacky - for one thing I'd be holding two copies of the data in memory at once, which might be an issue if the file is large. I'm exploring writing a custom deserializer. Thanks for your input though.